# Cassandre did not delete old sstables created by full compact

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have a CF and set TTL as 10 days. I also have a cron job which runs every 2 days. I can see merged sstable after compaction. however,sometime, I can still see some sstables which were created/updated by full compaction more 10 days ago in disk. Even restarting could not force Cassandra to delete those old files. Anyway to get rid of them.

Comment: Are these in your snapshots directory?

Comment: No. there located in normal directory.

Comment: Which compaction strategy are you using?

Comment: sizeTieredCompactionStrategy